# Allocation in ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

i am facing one problem i.e in ARC enable project if add buttons to scroll view by adjusting its y position,then allocation is showing that 50%. But in ARC it should not display right. That for loop may iterate 15000 times . And i got unbounded memory growth,i observed that progress bar getting lazy when the count is increasing.Example code is

```
 static int i;

 for(;i<15000;i++)
 {
     UIButton *but = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
     but.frame     = CGRectMake(50, j, 60, 30);  
     j = j+30;
     [_scroll addSubview:but]; 
 }
```

here i am getting 50% allocation.

```
but.frame=CGRectMake(50, j, 60, 30);
```

Comment: You should not be adding 15000 buttons to a scroll view; that's a terrible UI. If you need a lot of repeating items, you should use a table view.

Comment: i need to do one SMS app . That adds greater than 15000 contacts. and all contacts should be in bubbled manner .will it be possible first.

Comment: Consider using UITableView.

Comment: You can do that with a table view, which only needs to create as many cells as you can see on screen. It reuses these cells, so that is much more efficient than trying to add 15000 buttons to a scroll view.

Comment: But here i want know the reason please..

Comment: UITableView can reuse the cell which is not visible, that save lots of memory.

Comment: @murali If you use `UIScrollView` the objects on `UIScrollView` will not be reused. It allocates 15000 objects. On the other hand, if you use `UITableView`, cells will be reused. It means the object which are displayed will be allocated.

Comment: Thank you very much to all. you have given excellent answers

Comment: @murali please tick the green checkmark of an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the setup is not quite right for your context.

Your app slowed down because it was using so much memory due to the instantiation of 15000 `UIButton` objects.

You said that you need to have so many instances, because you are doing some sort of list for contacts. This is exactly the use case for `UITableView` or `UITableViewController` (it's the same UI control that Apple uses in its own preinstalled apps).

It allows you to reuse the *cell* objects (instances of class `UITableViewCell`) instead of creating a whole new object for every contact you want to display.

You will have to implement the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols for the setup to work. These are not too trivial *at first sight*, but you'll get acquainted to the underlying mechanism rather quickly once you start to take off. I'd recommend you to start with a simple tutorial and then move on to your particular case from there.

Answer (score 0):

**Do not reinvent the wheel !**

As the previous speakers already pointed out you should use a `UITableView`.

But you do not have to reinvent the wheel. There are a lot of implementations out there which face exactly this problem.

Here you can find a good implementation which already uses a `UITableView` (1: Objective-C, 2:Swift).
[SSMessagesViewController](https://github.com/samsoffes/ssmessagesviewcontroller/tree/master/Classes)

[Acani Chats](https://github.com/acani/Chats/tree/master/Chats/Chats)

What it basically does is:

- Use a custom `UIView` to display the "bubbles"
- Use this custom `UIView` to display in a custom `UITableViewCell`
- Use this custom `UITableViewCell` to be displayed in a `UITableView` which manages to get a high perfomance for your task